# netmiko connection error - TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passphrase'

Tags: python, cisco

I'm taking my first steps with netmiko and trying a basic connection:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip="10.118.10.8", username="name", password="passowrd")
output = device.send_command("show version")
print output
device.disconnect()
```

I've tries device_type="cisco_ios" and arista_eos, on both occasions I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "netmiko_v1.py", line 3, in <module>
device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip="10.118.10.8", username="name", password="password")
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 205, in ConnectHandler
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 270, in __init__
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 766, in establish_connection
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passphrase'
```

I'm assuming I'm getting something very simple and obvious wrong, any suggestions?

To add packet capture shows nothing toward target IP addresses so assuming this is a local issue. Due to lack of privileges on host I had to install netmiko in user-space, not sure if this could cause issues?

Comment: How did you install Netmiko? If you installed via the 'develop' branch on GitHub, you probably should re-install a the 2.2.2 released version.

Answer (score 1):

It is not netmiko issue. It is the paramiko library it uses seems to have some issue. Make sure you upgrade your paramiko version on your setup to latest one (here in my case 2.4.1) :-

```
    >>> import paramiko
    >>> print paramiko.__version__
    2.4.1

    I saw this issue if the version of paramiko is 2.0.0 or less
    ##### Log Below ########
    >>> import paramiko
    >>> print paramiko.__version__
    2.0.0

    >>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler
    >>> dut1 = {
    ...     'device_type': 'vyos',
    ...     'ip': 'X.X.X.X',
    ...     'username': 'XXXX',
    ...     'password': 'XXX',
    ... }
    >>> t = ConnectHandler(**dut1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 210, in ConnectHandler
        return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
      File "netmiko/base_connection.py", line 270, in __init__
        self.establish_connection()
      File "netmiko/base_connection.py", line 766, in establish_connection
        self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passphrase'

 Hope this helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a Netmiko issue as it means I need to roll the Netmiko version requirements to specify a newer version of Paramiko, but yes that will probably fix it.